# How to get last value and sum a group of values in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do get the last value of  net_insurance of each policy and sum by type_money

```
|policies|
 |id|  |policy_num|  |type_money| 
  1      1234            1
  2      5678            1
  3      3444            2
  4      4577            2


|insurances|
 |id|  |policy_id|  |net_insurance|
  1       1             100
  2       1             200 
  3       1             400
  4       2             500
  5       2             600
  6       3             100
  7       4             200
```

Here I'm trying to get the last value

```
semi result bedore to do the sum            

 |policy_num|  |type_money|  |last_net_insurance|
   1234          1            400
   5678          1            600
   3444          2            100
   4577          2            200
```

After getting the last value I want to sum by type_money that's what I really need

```
 |type money|    |sum|
   1              1000
   2               300
```

I tried this but I don't know how to get the last net_insurance of each policy and also do a sum

```
  select * from policies
  inner join insurances ON (insurances.policy_id =policies.id)
  group by policies.id
```

Here is the page where I'm doing this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acd8e/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
SELECT p.type_money, sum(i1.net_insurance) total FROM (
  SELECT max(id) id FROM insurances
  GROUP BY policy_id
) i2
JOIN insurances i1 USING (id)
JOIN policies p ON p.id = i1.policy_id
GROUP BY p.type_money
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72f5c/1).

BTW, absolute +1 for providing the fiddle and adding your sample query :)

Comment: Fantastic help!!! that's what i needed sir :) you are so great.Thank you so much and thanks i tried Fiddle because is better show what i'm doing

Comment: Absolutely, it makes things much more easy to us ^.^